# set new page in HTML using iTextSharp HTMLWorker (html to pdf)

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I using iTextSharp (V 5.4.2.0) to convert a html page to pdf. But I would like to be able to set a new page.

I've tried this:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

and the tag `<newpage />`

But it doesn't work.
What is the best way, to create a html page, including new page tags (or something) to be able to convert it correctly using iTextSharp?

Kind regards,

Matthijs

Comment: The HTMLWorker class is deprecated and no longer supported. Instead you are encouraged to use the XMLWorker. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.html

Comment: ah...too bad :-( ok, if I cannot make a workaround, I'll guess I have to check how  XHTML/CSS works with XML Worker... thanks!

Comment: XMLWorker seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the iTextSharp [XML Worker library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker) and then use this HTML:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: hi, after a while I indeed used the XMLWorker. And that worked. ;-)

Comment: I dont want to install xml worker library, but still want page break in PDF from HTML string. Kindly help me to resolve the issue ASAP.

Comment: Why don't you want to install the worker library? Some type of deployment issue?

Answer (score 1):

A `<np />` tag in your HTML inserts a page break in the Document/PDF.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I don't know what this tag does but it surely works. @Stefan  Do you have any documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in C#
document.NewPage();