# How to generate mutiple page using PdfWriter

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, itextpdf

I am generating pdf file for payslip using PdfWriter in C#. And I'm downloading the pdf file from html code, every user it will create a table (<table>...</table>) and every table display in new page.
But all table are displayed in same page.

eg

Page 1
 Employee 1 Details
may the details will come to the next page.

Page 2
 Employee 2 Details

Page 3
 Employee 2 details
Page 4
 Employee 3 details

.....
.....
....

But Now my output will come
Page 1
 Employee 1
 Employee 2
Page 2 
Employee 3
Employee 4
 Employee 5
.....

My code is

```
StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
stb.Append(All.ToString());
EXP.InnerHtml = stb.ToString();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);


string resHtml = "";

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    resHtml+="<table width='100%'><tr><td align='center'>payslip"+ i+"</td></tr></table>"; 
}
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(resHtml);
Doc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 50f, 20f);

HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(Doc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, Response.OutputStream);
Doc.Open();
htmlparser.Open(); 
htmlparser.Parse(stringReader);
htmlparser.Close();
Doc.Close();
Response.Write(Doc);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `HTMLWorker`. That class is deprecated: it is no longer supported as it has been abandoned in favor of [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker). There are different ways to solve your problem.

**Create multiple small HTML files instead of one big HTML**

I wouldn't create one long table for every employee, but a single table for every employee, and introduce `document.NewPage()` after adding every table.
See **Answer #2** to the question [How to parse multiple HTML files into a single PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814701/itextsharp-how-to-use-htmlworker-to-covert-html-to-pdf-with-pagination)

This is some Java code (you can read it as if it were pseudo code):

```
public void createPdf(Employees employees) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    document.open();
    String css = readCSS();
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        String html = createHtml(employee);
        ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html, css);
        for (Element e : list) {
            document.add(e);
        }
        document.newPage();
    }
    document.close();
}
```

This solution is the best solution from the point of view of memory and CPU use.

**Create one big HTML and introduce page breaks**

Another option is to introduce a page break before every employee table. See [set new page in HTML using iTextSharp HTMLWorker (html to pdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043029/set-new-page-in-html-using-itextsharp-htmlworker-html-to-pdf)

This isn't a good idea as you build up a large chunk of data in memory and that memory can only be released after the PDF is rendered. iTextSharp tries to flush pages to the `OutputStream` as soon as possible. If you create small HTML files, and add them to the PDF immediately, you can discard the HTML bytes from memory sooner rather than later and iTextSharp will also be able to flush content streams to the output, releasing memory that is needed to store that content.

**Important notice:**

Obviously, these answers imply that you do the right thing. That is: throw away your code that relies on the abandoned `HTMLWorker` and start using XML Worker.

Answer (score 0):

You can append pagebreak after every  tag and append  before  tag.
This will give you a string like,
.................

following is the code to split the html string.

```
Dim myString As String = sb.ToString()
Dim mySplit As String = "pagebreak"
Dim myResult() As String = myString.Split(New String() {mySplit}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

To render each html string on new page,

```
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream)
            pdfDoc.Open()
            For Each r As String In myResult
                Dim sr As New StringReader(r)
                htmlparser.Parse(sr)
                pdfDoc.NewPage()
                sr.Dispose()
            Next
            pdfDoc.Close()
            Dim bytes As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()
            memoryStream.Close()
            Response.Clear()
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.pdf")
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
            Response.[End]()
            Response.Close()
        End Using
```

Answer (score -1):

If your html content is fixed then you can with page break but if your HTML content is variable then it will be different to predict when page is start and finish.

Comment: html content is different, then what can I do?

Comment: Then your need to write whole printing library like I.e A4 size total character content count. So based on your html content you need to do some math calculate about page number. It’s not robust solution but hopefully  it will woks

Comment: Dear @jalil, I'm sorry, but I don't understand how your answer solves the problem. You may want to produce some code that shows what you mean.